# Default current time to Eastern Standard time

Tags: infopath2010

I have an Infopath form (linked to a sharepoint 2010 list) that contains a text box field that shows the current time. My problem is that some of my target users are working in different time zones and I want the field to calcualte the current time in Eastern Standard time.

Im currently using this formula as the default value for the text box:

substring-after(now(), "T")

Is there a way to manipulate this function to show the current time in EST. If not, then im open to any suggestions.

Thank you,